# OpenLDAP as a proxy for multiple LDAP servers not returning mapped attributes properly

Tags: openldap

We want to use OpenLDAP to proxy multiple customer LDAP servers we have, e.g. normal LDAP in Linux and Windows AD etc. Since there are multiple LDAP servers proxied, we also needed one to many attribute mappings. So in the `slapd.conf` file, we defined the rwm overlay section as below.

```
overlay       rwm
rwm-map       attribute   lastName  sAMAccountName

overlay rwm
rwm-map attribute email emailAddress
rwm-map attribute mobileNumber mobile
rwm-map attribute lastName sn
rwm-map attribute uid uid
rwm-map attribute firstName givenName
rwm-map objectClass inetOrgPerson person
```

Note that how `lastName` maps to both `sn` and `sAMAccountName`. I understand entries like `lastName` or `mobileNumber` are not legitimate LDAP attributes with valid OIDs defined in a schema. That's why there is below warning when starting slapd. But let's just leave that as it is for now.

`5a71c27c /etc/openldap/slapd.conf: line 125: warning, source attributeType 'lastName' should be defined in schema`

The proxy itself works. We can use it to query a user and get all attributes that are available. And the mappings can also be successfully done.

But strangely if we specify mapped attributes in the `ldapsearch` call as below, those attributes won't be successfully retrieved.

```
ldapsearch -h localhost -x -b "dc=local,dc=foo,dc=bar,dc=com" "mail=someone@foo.bar.com" lastname firstname mobilenumber
```

Only the `dn` attribute is shown in the output. And if we add one more attribute that is default from the LDAP server. All of them can be successfully retrieved.

```
ldapsearch -h localhost -x -b "dc=local,dc=foo,dc=bar,dc=com" "mail=someone@foo.bar.com" lastname firstname mobilenumber notesemail
```

We don't know much about OpenLDAP. Just want to get this proxy work first. So wondering if above configuration is a valid tryout.

Answer (score 0):

You are naming foreign attributes to the local server in your search filter. It doesn't know about them, because they have been mapped. You need to use the mapped name, e.g. `givenName`.

Comment: Thanks for replying, but it's not answering the question posted.

Comment: @RuifengMa Of course it is, and your own answer confirms it.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I found out that the trick is to NOT use the `rwm overlay` at all. Instead just using the `map` statement after the `uri` directive is sufficient enough. So in the database declaration section, instead of

```
database meta
suffix "dc=foo,dc=bar,dc=com"
rootdn "cn=admin,dc=foo,dc=bar,dc=com"
rootpw "p@ssw0rd"

uri "ldaps://tstbluepages.mkm.can.ibm.com:636/dc=foo,dc=bar,dc=com"
lastmod off
readonly yes
suffixmassage "dc=foo,dc=bar,dc=com" "ou=bluepages,o=ibm.com"

uri "ldaps://<AD_HOSTNAME>:636/dc=local,dc=foo,dc=bar,dc=com"
lastmod off
readonly yes
suffixmassage "dc=foo,dc=bar,dc=com" "dc=testad,dc=ibm,dc=com"

overlay       rwm
rwm-map       attribute   lastName  sAMAccountName

overlay rwm
rwm-map attribute email emailAddress
rwm-map attribute mobileNumber mobile
rwm-map attribute lastName sn
rwm-map attribute uid uid
rwm-map attribute firstName givenName
rwm-map objectClass inetOrgPerson person
```

now the `slapd.conf` file has below section.

```
database meta
suffix "dc=foo,dc=bar,dc=com"
rootdn "cn=admin,dc=foo,dc=bar,dc=com"
rootpw "p@ssw0rd"

uri "ldaps://tstbluepages.mkm.can.ibm.com:636/dc=foo,dc=bar,dc=com"
lastmod off
readonly yes
suffixmassage "dc=foo,dc=bar,dc=com" "ou=bluepages,o=ibm.com"
map attribute mobileNumber mobile
map attribute email emailAddress
map attribute lastName sn
map attribute firstName givenName
map objectClass inetOrgPerson person


uri "ldaps://<AD_HOSTNAME>:636/dc=foo,dc=bar,dc=com"
lastmod off
readonly yes
suffixmassage "dc=foo,dc=bar,dc=com" "dc=testad,dc=ibm,dc=com"
map attribute lastName  sAMAccountName
```

I know that the [slapd-ldap](http://www.openldap.org/software/man.cgi?query=slapd-ldap&sektion=5&apropos=0&manpath=OpenLDAP%202.4-Release) manpage says that the functionality of the `map` directive is delegated to the `rwm overlay`, but the [slapd-meta](http://www.openldap.org/software/man.cgi?query=slapd-meta&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=OpenLDAP%202.4-Release&format=html) manpage still has the `map` directive listed and it works.

This well served our original purpose of mapping different attributes from multiple back-end LDAP servers into a uniform one.